# 406 not acceptable when using HttpPost on android

Tags: php, android, post, httpclient

I want to using HttpPost to post data to my web site.
and here is my code

```
String st = "http://www.yade.cc/huli/classget/search.php";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();        
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(st);       
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", str));
UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(ent);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);           
String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),"utf-8");
```

but the result is:

> 406 Not Acceptable
>   An appropriate representation of the requested resource /huli/classget/search.php could 
>   not be found on this server
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument
>   to handle the request.

when I  add user-agent data into mycode, it works.

```
post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Chrome/28.0.1500.95");
```

but the result is something like
   口口口口口口result口口口口

口means the char i can not see and i dont know what it is.

I try to use php to do the same thing, the result is totally ok, nothing strange appeared.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! First up, this is a well formed question: precise detailing of the problem and a well sized code sample. Sadly, it looks far more likely that your real problem is that your server isn't configured correctly! "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." is the give away really. On the ohter hand, 406 is a fantastic funky status code, so if you can confirm your server is fine (what framework are you using?) we may yet proceed...

Comment: PS: it looks a bit like you might be using a "deprecated" (though not officially I notice) client- is that the apache client I see?